# play background sound during a call in android as root

Tags: android

I am trying to create an app that will play background sound during a call.
I have read that it is impossible to do if you are using the SDK, but what about the NDK?

What about root privilages? can it help?

Thanks

Comment: from what I have checked there are no such thing, and it is currently impossible in android 2.3.3.